# Javascript - replace all numeric hash tags

Tags: javascript, regex, formula, hashtag

I need all numeric hash tags replace with actual number.

Consider this code:

```
var test = '#1 *#1*#137-#137 *Math.PI';

test = test.replace(/#1/g, '666');
test = test.replace(/#137/g, '444');
```

It will return:

```
666 *666*66637-66637 *Math.PI
```

the first regexp for #1 will replace #137 as well, because it contains #1.

The goal is:

```
666 *666*444-444 *Math.PI
```

Here is JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/U3eX2/

Any idea?

Comment: Pleeeeaaasseeee don't use `eval` to execute that code later.

Comment: @Allendar, how would you suggest to let user write a formula and then calculate it?

Comment: Because your string has a standard JavaScript object+method in it :P  `Math.PI`

Comment: @Allendar, well, I know why I shouldn't do it but I asked if you know about another way I could go. I couldn't find any. And if there is only one, I have no choice, right?

Comment: If you have the facilities it might be better to collect the variables separately from each other and/or send it through AJAX to a server-side script. That way you could split the string up there and calculate the formulas. Splitting on client side should not be so hard either. It depends on what code logic you want to protect in your code.

Comment: BTW, I finally found nice JS library for evaluating math formula without eval(): http://silentmatt.com/javascript-expression-evaluator/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a simple negative lookbehind:

```
var test = '#1 *#1*#137-#137 *Math.PI';

test = test.replace(/#1(?!\d)/g, '666');
test = test.replace(/#137/g, '444');

$('div').text(test);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U3eX2/1/